# How to configure TLS connections to protect them from freak attack (CVE 2015-0204)?

Tags: java, ssl, jsse

For the vulnerabilty see https://freakattack.com/.

Mozilla wiki has a page with recommendations for ciphersuites: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Recommended_configurations

How would I apply those or similar recommendations in the Java context (SSLContext, provider configuration, Tomcat connectors etc.)?

Comment: Remove all the RSA export ciphers from the enabled cipher suites.

Comment: @EJP, can you show a snippet of where to start?

Comment: Ah.. as shown here, POODLE(SSLv3) and FREAK(export-grade) are no problem in java7, because of policy setting.    
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#footnote1-1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Java 7 onwards cipher suites can be excluded from use via a security policy file called java.security that’s located under Java Runtime Environment in the /lib/security directory.

The policy file defines the jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms property to control TLS cipher selection. There is also a complementary property jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms to control algorithms encountered in SSL certificates. You can find the documentation for this property on the Oracle website: [JSSE Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#DisabledAlgorithms)

By default, as of Java 7 the following policy applies: jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=MD5, SHA1, DSA, RSA keySize < 2048
This means: no MD5, no SHA1, no DSA. RSA is allowed only if the key is at least 2048 bits long.
You can use this property to further tailor a site deployment to specific needs. All the cipher suites enabled by default in Java are found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider) under section Ciphers (unless the default SunJSSE crypto provider has been explicitly overridden and is not used).

As you can see all EXPORT cipher suites are disabled by default, so there is no need to configure something for the FREAK attack.

**Edit because of above comment of Houtman on question:**
About POODLE: You have to think about this both in java 7 and 8. Because the SSLv3 protocol has only been disabled by default from JDK 8u31 (see section Protocols [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider)).

Comment: If I want to disable TLS v 1.1, what should I put? The link you put, and from the sources I have found, I cannot see any reference. Like what is put in `java.security`, we have `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=MD5, SSLv3, DSA, RSA keySize < 2048`, so I suppose I can put it like `TLSv1.1`?

Comment: Indeed. e.g. to enable only TLS1.2 do: jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms= SSLv2Hello, SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1

Answer (score 0):

You can enable a list of cipher suites you want to use, refer setEnabledCipherSuites method in SSLSocket API and can exclude EXPORT cipher suites from this list

Answer (score 0):

Add these to your SSL connector

server="Unspecified" xpoweredBy="false" secure="true"
sslProtocol="TLS" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" 
ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"